# Matching with unique identifier for HTML nodes in an inconsistent DOM tree

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, dom, treemap

Here's the challenge:

I have two browsers where each renders an "almost-the-same" DOM tree.
The differences may be in class names, notating the browser type, like:

```
<div class="square ff"></div>
<div class="square IE"></div>
```

Where the first might appear on firefox, and the second on an IE browser.
These divs, other than their notation are the same, and as so need to receive the same ID.

Other differences may be implied: different placement -> different XPath, elements which are removed from the DOM, extensions on the browser itself; interfering with the DOM etc...

In theory, I would like to take all of their properties, including: tag name, attributes, parent attributes etc.. and create a unique identifier which will be consistent across a varying DOM.

The best solution would be one where I won't have to compare any of the ID maps with one another, although, it might be possible, in which case I'd like the matching percentage to be a part of the ID (i.e, 2374-75, where 2374 is the ID and 75 is the match %)

The second challenge is finding element X on one side - in the other.

I'll be updating this question in accordance with your comments,
thanks,
Mike.

Comment: I've created some small JS bookmark that calculates the placement in the DOM tree a while ago which might be of interest to you; however it will brilliantly fail if the nodes have a different Xpath as you say. You can check it out here: http://output.jsbin.com/qobugu/3?phighlight=0,1,1,0 (note: if you follow this link, drag the `getLink` bookmark to your browser and click it, the words 'Click a block' should be highlighted)

Comment: That's quite an elaborate solution, however xpath is sitll an issue indeed.
I've found a quite elaborate way to achieve such mapping, however, I don't like it due to its complexity. I'll keep looking, thanks!